# Mounting NFS in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, nfs

I successfully managed to mount an NSF export at a local folder as a mount point. I can type `ls` and see the remote content. However, I do not see any remote files in Explorer - It is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't mount my NFS share directly in Cygwin - how did you do that? Please see my [**question here**](https://superuser.com/q/1240950/187555). Thanks!

Comment: I am actually not able to mount now. I can mount shares, but cannot even `cd` into the mount point! I should have included the commands in the original post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin only mounts the NFS export inside Cygwin itself (i.e., all programs using the cygwin DLL). You need to use a native NFS client in order to see remote files from other Windows programs such as Explorer.

Apparently Windows includes such a client, but you need to enable it using "Turn Windows features on and off". See: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/nfs-client-for-windows-7/42aae25d-d077-4ff9-abdf-7314a589c46d

Comment: It has been excluded from Windows 8 :-(

Comment: @Lord Seems to be available in Windows 8 Enterprise according to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/525473/how-do-i-mount-an-nfs-share-in-windows-8). Another option is to install Samba on the server.

Comment: Windows 10 has a nfs client: https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/. However, I'm afraid that its "mount" program will then conflict with cygwin's "mount"?