# How to mount NFS share in Cygwin?

Tags: mount, cygwin, nfs

The question [Mounting NFS in Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/805374/mounting-nfs-in-cygwin) suggests it is possible to directly mount a NFS share (we have a NFS server running on a linux machine) in the Cygwin file system, even though the [The Cygwin Mount Table documentation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table) doesn't mention that.

I have done some searching but couldn't find any solutions on how to do that, most articles suggest mounting from a Samba share instead.

I think directly mounting through NFS would be preferable as it'll avoid the translation of the POSIX permissions (from the GNU/Linux server) to Windows permissions and then back to Cygwin (POSIX) permissions but have the permissions in my Cygwin environment directly match the ones that are effective on the GNU/Linux NFS server's share.

I tried the following on the command line:

```
$ mount server:/share /local/mountpoint
> mount: /local/mountpoint: Invalid argument
$ mount server:/share /local/mountpoint nfs binary,posix=1
> mount: too many arguments
$ mount -fsb //server/share /local/mountpoint
> mount: unknown option -- s
$ mount -t nfs //server/share /local/mountpoint
> mount: unknown option -- t
```

Or in `/etc/fstab`:

```
server:/share /local/mountpoint nfs binary,posix=1
# or
//server/share /local/mountpoint nfs binary,posix=1
```

None of them resulted in successful mounts.

How can I mount my NFS share directly in Cygwin? Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mounting NFS in Cygwin](https://superuser.com/questions/805374/mounting-nfs-in-cygwin)

Comment: I invite any close-voter to be a little bit helpful and give the answer to this question in a comment.  It should be easy, if you believe that Lord Loh’s question thread contains the answer to this (FriendFX’s) question — just *quote* (copy and paste) the answer.  If you can’t do that, why are you voting to close as a duplicate?

Comment: @Scott thanks for helping to keep this open. Maybe I just should accept (literally and figuratively) [the answer by matzeri](https://superuser.com/a/1241279/187555)? I was still hoping that there's a way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can not as Cygwin has no client NFS program. To mount a NFS point you need a filesystem driver