# How do I mount an NFS share in Windows 10 upgraded from Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, mount, windows-10-upgrade, nfs

I upgraded a very seldom used Windows 7 **Ultimate** machine to Windows 10.  What I liked about Win7 Ultimate was the built-in (but not default) feature to mount Linux based NFS server volumes from Win7 **Ultimate**.

The Windows 10 upgrade intro said all my files will be exactly like they used-to-be.  However, services for Unix or NFS Client are not options in the feature set of the Windows 10 upgrade.

The thread linked in comments refers to Windows 8, and points to [Microsoft KB 2769923](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769923).  That reference describes upgrading from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8, and states that in Win 8, only the Enterprise edition supports Services for NFS.

How does one mount an NFS share in Win 10 upgraded from Windows 7 Ultimate?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/525473/how-do-i-mount-an-nfs-share-in-windows-8 and see if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried this http://superuser.com/questions/525473/how-do-i-mount-an-nfs-share-in-windows-8 ?

Comment: Services for Unix is not a feature option in the versions of Windows 10 i have used.

Comment: Apparently, the NFS Client is available in Pro since the Redstone Update (AKA Anniversary Update/1607). A bug may prevent it from working though, see [this discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c1b1d99f-ba29-41f7-af4c-e5ec2e5f8b69/client-for-nfs-is-not-licensed-for-use-on-this-version-of-windows-error-windows-10-1439310?forum=WindowsInsiderPreview) for more information. I don't have Windows 10 anymore, so I cannot test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A post from [freenas.org](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/how-to-connect-to-nfs-share-from-windows-10.44412/) indicates that there has been some progress on MS side and currently (as of 2/2/2017) my Win 10 Pro does offer NFS support. Quoting freenas.org:

> "Go to control panel, add and remove programs, Windows features, check the boxes > for NFS"

This works for me to the extent of being able to run `mount \\<NAS IP>\<share> N:`.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 does not allow NFS connections. This is part of the new policy from Microsoft, with each new release of Windows 10 features are removed from the consumer versions. First port bonding was removed then NFS support etc. They want you to buy the most expensive Windows Enterprise version if you use your windows to more than Facebook and Solitare.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. NFS is available in "Ultimate" and "Enterprise" versions.

Comment: Link to "Windows 10 Ultimate" please. (It doesn't exist AFAICT.)

Comment: Answer is correct. I am talking about Windows consumer versions from where Microsoft is removing features with each new update.